# Passing data to background event object in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Is there a way to get a data that I passed to eventObj when user clicks on background event?
My sample background event looks like this:

```
{
 id: 'availableForMeeting',
 title: 'Test Background Event #1',
 start: '2015-08-13T07:30:00',
 end: '2015-08-13T12:30:00',
 rendering: 'background',
 sampleId: 214,
 color: 'red'
}
```

But I can't get sampleId field, 'cause it doesn't exist in jsEvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order to actually get a click handler on a background event, you have to use a delegated jquery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because FullCalendar's [`eventClick`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) doesn't work for background events.

```
$("#calendar").on("click",".fc-bgevent",function(event){
    console.log($(this).data());
});
```

With just that, you will get an empty console log. We need to add the event data to the event element. We can do this in [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

```
eventRender: function(event,element,view){
    $(element).data(event);
},
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/6h5z5k0v/)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didnt worked for me as I cant trigger the click due to multiple issues(`z-index`, `height`). I think I found a much cleaner solution.

The solution is to use the `fullcalendar` [clientEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents) method. It will use the client side copy of the `events`. So no extra `api` call.

Both  `select` and `dayClick` will gets fired when selecting a date. So choose the one that best suits your needs. I think `select` is a good choice as it gets fired for multiple days selection aswell if needed.

```
    select: function (startDate, endDate, jsEvent, view, resource) {

       //below code for passing events in bg events of fullcalender
                          var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (evt) {
                        //if same date as clicked date add element to events array
                          return evt.start.isSame(startDate);//must return boolean
                    });



                    console.log(events);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.