# cant target certain element in jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Here is the html(just of the td element. This is generated by fullcalendar)

```
<td class="fc-widget-content"> //can reach till here
   <div style="height: 37px;">
      <div class="fc-event-container" style="height: 0px;"></div>
      <div class="fc-bgevent-container">

         //want to target below element
         <div class="fc-bgevent" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 0px; right: -101px;"></div> 

</div>
   </div>
</td>
```

When using event delegation in jquery cant target below element.

```
   $("#pricing-calendar").on("click",".fc-bgevent",function(event){
        console.log($(this).data());
    });
```

But if I do this it will work(this is the closest I can get to .`fc-bgevent div`)

```
$("#pricing-calendar").on("click",".fc-widget-content",function(event){
    console.log($(this).data());
});
```

Could someone tell me how to achieve this?

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkk8nLmq/6/) (with just static content(Only Friday 1 have event class so when clicking that should fire))

**Update**

If someone have this same issue with fullcalendar please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009342/passing-data-to-background-event-object-in-fullcalendar/50636329#50636329)

Comment: Try to use selector : `$("#pricing-calendar").on("click",".fc-widget-content > div > .fc-bgevent",function(event){
    console.log($(this).data());
});` I haven't test it.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces issue

Comment: @charlietfl updated with fiddle

Comment: @Alee wont work

Comment: @Abhilash please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your code doesn't work is that because your div with `fc-bgevent` class has no height so that it is not possible to click on it. if you set it's height (eg. set it to 10 pixel) then you would be able to click on it:

```js
$("#pricing").on("click",".fc-bgevent",function(event){
    alert("ljfkjgd");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="pricing">
<tr>
<td class="fc-widget-content"> //can reach till here
   <div style="height: 37px;">
      <div class="fc-event-container" style="height: 0px;"></div>
      <div class="fc-bgevent-container">

         //want to target below element
         <div class="fc-bgevent" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 0px; right: -101px; height:10px"></div> 

</div>
   </div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

according to your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkk8nLmq/6/), the second reason that your code is not working is that there is a `div` with class `fc-bg` which cover all of your main table. one approach to overcome this problem is using `z-index` attribute. here i set your `fc-bg` div's `z-index`  to -1 and your code work:

[**Working Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fybady3s/2/)

Comment: The codesnippet works. But in my html not working. I have updated the question with a fiddle of full fullcalender generated html

Comment: still not solving my issue as its dynamically generated by fullcalender. But for the question asked this is the reason why it wont work in static cases. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/drzx0zxg/

I have used `$(document).on()`.

Comment: not working in my case. I have created a fiddle. Please have a look if possible.